# How to get voxel coordinates(as in ITK snap ) from vtkimage viewer from mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, itk

I am trying to use ITK’s region growing algorithm for medical image segmentation. So to put the seedpoint i need exact voxel coordinates of the mouseclick position in my vtkimageviewer. So how can I get those voxel coordinates(as in ITK snap tool) from my vtkimage viewer. Currently I am able to get VTK World Coordinates using pick point picker . Now how to convert this vtk world coordinates to voxel coordinates as in ITK snap tool …
Please help me with this information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly my problem statement is , I am having Multiplanar reconstruction window and I am using multiplanar reconstruction window(MPR) and I am using vtkResliceCursorWidget for getting the coordinates . For now I am able to get vtk world coordinates. Now how do I need to convert these coordinates to voxel/array coordinates similar to ITK SNAP/3D slicer .

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ijkIndex = itkImage->TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(worldCoordinates);](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageBase.html#ae46118e0a604c11e6f1170da7c478f81)